# Salesforce Code Analyzer: (DFA) InternalExecutionError

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, security-review, app-development

I am preparing to send a new managed package for security review but am seeing a few issues being flagged in the Salesforce Code Analyzer DFA report and am unsure if this would be a false positive or a genuine issue, i think its complaining as the return object is a custom object thats included in the package.... the DatabaseFLS class does all of the schema validation checks and access checks.

If this is a false positive how would you detail this in a False Positive Report?

For example I have the below global method:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
// update an existing Object Link Record
global static void updateObjectLink(Object_Link__c updObjectLinkRec){
    system.debug('updateObjectLink: method called.');

    String[] accessFields = objectLinkFields();


    if (!DatabaseFLS.flsSelect('Object_Link__c', accessFields)) {
        throw new CPQCustomException('updateObjectLink: Error accessing fields. Check that the user has the required rights.');
    }

    try{
        DatabaseFLS.flsUpsert(updObjectLinkRec);
    }Catch(Exception e){
        throw new CPQCustomException('updateObjectLink: Error updating the existing Object Link Record. ');
    }
}
```

This is being flagged in the DFA report with the below error:

**Rule:** InternalExecutionError

**URL:** https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/v3.x/salesforce-graph-engine/rules/#ApexFlsViolationRule

**Category:** InternalExecutionError

**Engine:** sfge

**Description:**

```
Graph Engine identified your source and sink, but you must manually verify that you have a sanitizer in this path. Then, add an engine directive to skip the path. Next, create a Github issue for the Code Analyzer team that includes the error and stack trace. After we fix this issue, check the Code Analyzer release notes for more info. Error and stacktrace: UnexpectedException: SObjectType is not available in DescribeSObjectResult: ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.DescribeSObjectResult'} ApexValue(DescribeSObjectResult) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectField'} ApexValue(SObjectField) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexValue(ApexFieldDescribeMapValue) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.DescribeSObjectResult'} ApexValue(DescribeSObjectResult) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=SObjectType{associatedObjectType='null'} ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectType'} ApexValue(SObjectType) {status=INDETERMINANT, declarationVertex=SObjectType{associatedObjectType='null'} ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectType'} ApexValue(SObjectType) {status=INDETERMINANT, declarationVertex=VariableDeclaration{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=3, Type=SObjectType, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=3, Name_CaseSafe=r, childIdx=1, BeginColumn=21, Name=r}}, valueVertex=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getSObjectType, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=3, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=3, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getSObjectType, BeginLine=3, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=3, MethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, MethodName=getSObjectType}}, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=null, invocableExpression=null, method=null}, valueVertex=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getSObjectType, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=3, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=3, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getSObjectType, BeginLine=3, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=3, MethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, MethodName=getSObjectType}}, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=null, invocableExpression=null, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=r.getDescribe, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[r], BeginLine=4, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, Name_CaseSafe=r, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=45, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=r}}}, chainedNames=[r], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=r.getDescribe, BeginLine=4, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=r.getdescribe, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, MethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=47, MethodName=getDescribe}}, method=Method{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=2, IsStandard=true, DefiningType_CaseSafe=schema.sobjecttype, LastChild=false, DefiningType=Schema.SObjectType, Constructor=false, EndLine=2, Name_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=1, ReturnType=Schema.DescribeSObjectResult, Name=getDescribe, Arity=0, ReturnType_CaseSafe=schema.describesobjectresult, BeginColumn=38}}}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=flsDescribe.fields.getMap, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[flsDescribe, fields], BeginLine=5, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=5, Name_CaseSafe=flsdescribe.fields, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=51, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=flsDescribe.fields}}}, chainedNames=[flsDescribe, fields], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=flsDescribe.fields.getMap, BeginLine=5, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=flsdescribe.fields.getmap, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=5, MethodName_CaseSafe=getmap, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=70, MethodName=getMap}}, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=mfields.get, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[mfields], BeginLine=12, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=12, Name_CaseSafe=mfields, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=18, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=mfields}}}, chainedNames=[mfields], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=mfields.get, BeginLine=12, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=mfields.get, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=12, MethodName_CaseSafe=get, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=26, MethodName=get}}, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getDescribe, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=12, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=12, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=44, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getDescribe, BeginLine=12, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=12, MethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=44, MethodName=getDescribe}}, method=Method{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=2, IsStandard=true, DefiningType_CaseSafe=schema.sobjectfield, LastChild=false, DefiningType=Schema.SObjectField, Constructor=false, EndLine=2, Name_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=1, ReturnType=Schema.DescribeFieldResult, Name=getDescribe, Arity=0, ReturnType_CaseSafe=schema.describefieldresult, BeginColumn=36}}}: com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.FlsValidationRepresentation.setObject(FlsValidationRepresentation.java:86);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.convert(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:183);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.checkForValidation(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:77);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.FlsValidationCentral.checkSchemaBasedFlsValidation(FlsValidationCentral.java:71);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.AbstractFlsVisitor.afterVisit(AbstractFlsVisitor.java:67);com.salesforce.graph.vertex.StandardConditionVertex$Negative.afterVisit(StandardConditionVertex.java:82)
```